# Custom "Pin It" button on hover (I am NOT using Blogger or WordPress)

Tags: javascript, hover, pinterest

I am making my own personal portfolio website and implementing the use of a Pinterest "Pin It" button when an image is hovered.  Is there any way I can customize the image that is used for the button?  I am not using WordPress or Blogger; this site is simply hosted on my school's server.

This is the only piece of code that controls the "Pin It" button as it is now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async  data-pin-shape="round" data-pin-height="32" data-pin-hover="true" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Probably have to use javascript to change the background image url in the css after the pinterest button has been rendered

Answer (score 0):

There are tutorials out there on how to do this with jQuery, I had to do this about a year ago I don't remember the URL of [the tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/12078/create-jquery-pinterest-pin-it-plugin), but I think this is it, but the test code I built is still running on [this gallery](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/AngkorMusk/AngkorMusk.html). I like the button to appear on hover like the actual Pinterest website, but my boss wanted that functionality removed.